# Google Play Store - "An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again later"

Tags: google-play-store, google-account, google

Since Yesterday I have been getting this message from the google play store when ever I try to save something to my wishlist. This has occurred both on the app and the web version of the play store. This is a problem I would like to resolve as fast as I can.

**My questions are:**

1. Is there a workaround for the google play store app (*Important*)
2. Has this happened to anyone else or is just on my google account (*Off topic as it is Android Independent, feel free to remove this part of the question*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Cause of the Problem

The cause was that googles play store wishlist has a limit placed on it. **The Limit is 100**

*(The info was gotten from Google Support)*

---

### The Fix (Very Simple)

**On The Phone:**

1. Open the Play Store app.
2. Go to the menu, My Wishlist, and tap the three-dot menu on the item.
3. Tap "Remove from wishlist" on the menu that shows up.

*Or*

1. Open the Play Store app.
2. Go to the menu then My Wishlist *(Differs from here on compared to the top)*
3. Click on the wanted item (that is the item you want to remove.
4. On the App page Click the wishlist button, this will remove the item from your wishlist

**On The Computer:**

1. Go to [Google Play Wishlist](https://play.google.com/wishlist)
2. Click on an item you wanted removed
3. Once the page loads click the button that says "Added to Wishlist" (When you hover over this it says "Remove"). Once clicked the item is removed from the wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

Well this happened to me when I used to install apps from playstore using a slow internet connection. For this I used to get the error notification in the notification bar. I used to long press the notification, goto app info, and 'Clear data' there. This used to work for me as playstore again syncs once opened. U can try if it works but recommend you not to clear data on other 3rd party apps as you may lose you data.

Comment: This is not just on the play store app, it also happens on the web version (launched on a computer). It still downloads perfectly fine, it just won't  add stuff to my wishlist. Also I have already tried this.