# What is the maximum number of apps in the Play Store wishlist?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-wishlist

What is the maximum number of apps that can be stored in the in the Play Store wishlist?

According to [this Android SE QA](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/128611/77524), it was 100 at the end of 2015.  In addition to now being outdated, the source of that info was Google Support, which is not always accurate with this type of thing.